# Android Market Image View

Tags: android, image, list, view, screenshot

I would like to do something like the android market when you view screen shots.

I have a list view and when they click on any one it takes them to a separate view where they can open several images related to the item then picked.

Is there a way to do this and if so how?  Sample code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Is there a way to do this?" -- yes. You might consider asking a more targeted question.

Comment: Do you think that perhaps you could enlighten me on some of the code to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques you should think about: `ListView` and `Activity` especially `Intent`

Listview tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
Listview and activities: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html